# How I can auto login with SwiftyDropbox?

Tags: swift, authentication, dropbox, autologin

I have an app with SwiftyDropbox that function correctly, but I need to insert email and password for Dropbox every time that I use the app.
The app it's only for my use, it's not a security problem if the app auto-login in my account.
I don't find examples or documentation to make an auto-login with SwiftyDropbox. It's possible?

Answer (score 2):

While the Dropbox API was designed with the intention that each user would link their own Dropbox account, in order to interact with their own files, it is technically possible to connect to just one account. We generally don't recommend doing so, for various technical and security reasons, but those won't apply if you're the only user anyway.

So, there are two ways to go about this:

1) [Implement the normal app authorization flow as documented](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#configure-your-project), and log in and authorize the app once per app installation. The SwiftyDropbox SDK will store the resulting access token for you, which you can [programmatically re-use after that point each time using `authorizedClient`](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#try-some-api-requests).

2) Manually retrieve an access token for your account and hard code it in to the app, [using the `DropboxClient` constructor shown here under "Initialize with manually retrieved auth token"](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#try-some-api-requests).